# Как проще и оптимальнее заставить цикл выполняться указанное время?

Tags: java

Подскажите способ, **как заставить цикл выполняться указанное время**?

Желательно найти наиболее оптимизированный и наиболее короткий способ.

**можно использовать любой тип цикла!**

для старта:

```
    while(/*работать 10 сек*/){
       //код
    }
```

---

Замечания по предложенным вариантам, их производительности, достоинствам и недостаткам также хотелось бы узнать!

Comment: а вариант перед началом цикла замерить текущее время, а в цикле на каждой итерации (или каждые 100 итераций, например) проверять разность не подойдет?

Comment: @BOPOH подойдет, но время на замер времени тоже тратится, так что будет погрешность какая-то

Comment: ну так потому и 100 итераций, если цикл быстро выполняется - можно и увеличить счетчик. И вопрос - а если код на каждой итерации будет работать чуть меньше 10 секунд, т.е. первая итерация - надо еще ждать, а во время выполнения второй итерации 10 секунд уже наступили. Код надо прерывать или давать выполниться и не запускать следующую итерацию?

Comment: @Timeable да, но если за эти 100 итераций успеет выполниться большое число лишних действий (после окончания времени)...   ведь время может измеряться в часах, минутах, миллисекундах или еще в чем-либо...    не страшно, если начатая операция (в момент окончания  времени) завершится позже времени - главное чтобы не было лишних действий после указанного времени.

Comment: А цикл должен блокировать выполнение основного потока проги или надо вынести в другой поток?

Comment: "не страшно, если начатая операция завершится позже времени, главное чтобы не было лишних действий после указанного времени" - это как понимать? Итерация состоит из двух шагов: A и B. Шаг A выполнился и время превысило предел - надо прерывать цикл или надо выполнить B и только тогда прерывать цикл? А если цикл будет прерван во время выполнения итерации A (например долго удаляли из базы данные одним запросом) - это плохо?

Comment: @BOPOH имелось ввиду: мы заранее не можем знать, как долго будет выполняться операция внутри цикла (может 1 миллисекунду,может 10 секунд). После завершения времени, начатая операция может завершиться, но не должно порождаться новых (в случае 100 итераций, время может успеть закончится, а так как мы проверяем условие завершения в каждой сотой итерации, то после окончания времени, может  выполниться 99 лишних операций).

Comment: while( !стоп ){код}. В самом процессе сделать проверку не дельту в  10сек, и если больше стоп. Не?

Comment: @Barmaley можно вынести в отдельный поток.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что значит "оптимизированный способ".
Если брать вариант "в лоб", то получится как-то так:

```
long endTime = System.nanoTime() + neededTime;
while(true) {
    //some method logic
    if (System.nanoTime() >= neededTime) return;
}
```

Но тут сразу много вопросов по поводу того, что время на замер времени тоже тратится и вообще зачем нужно выполнять кусок кода только определенное время?

Вариант с потоками:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Callable<Object> task = () -> {
    //some logic
    return null;
};
Future<Object> future = executor.submit(task);
try {
    Object result = future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    // handle the timeout
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // handle the interrupts
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // handle other exceptions
}
```

Comment: спасибо. Предлагайте любые варианты!   Хотелось бы рассмотреть как можно большее количество способов.

Comment: @ВиталийВихляев так не пойдёт. Вам нужно решение или количество?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Я  пытаюсь найти ОПТИМАЛЬНОЕ решение...  количество мне  не важно...  просто если человек пишет, что знает еще способ, то я хочу взглянуть и на него. Не видя альтернативных решений, нельзя говорить о оптимальности того или иного алгоритма.  Может мне  предложат не менее интересное решение чем @zzashpaupat(спасибо ему за несколько вариантов ).